# interface java and scip - not generating the right classes

Tags: scip

I followed the steps described in the README in scip/interfaces/jni and when I get to step 6: make, it compiles all right untill I get this error:

> In file included from src/JniScipLibraryLoader.c:25:0:
>   src/JniScipLibraryLoader.h:2:17: fatal error: jni.h: Aucun fichier ou
>   dossier de ce type compilation terminated. Makefile:516 : la recette
>   pour la cible « obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt/JniScipLibraryLoader.o » a
>   échouée make: *** [obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt/JniScipLibraryLoader.o]
>   Erreur 1

What I perhaps failed to do correctly (but I should like some advice) is creating the optional path to java (I tried creating a soft link to my JDK-folder, but it doesn't seems to do the trick).

Evidently, because of this error I fail to perform the tests in step 7.

Any help is greatly appreciated! (please bear in mind when responding that I'm not a full grown developer)

Comment: I downloaded the version from git and proceeded as explained in JSCIPOpt-master/INSTALL.md (I'm working on Linux).  I didn't perform the step 3a) as I haven't modified src/scipjni.i

The last step 3b) produced the following error:
-> compiling obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt/scipjni_wrap.o
src/scipjni_wrap.c:154:17: fatal error: jni.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
compilation terminated.
Makefile:80 : la recette pour la cible « library » a échouée
make: *** [library] Erreur 1

Have I linked the wrong libraries? And if yes, which ones?

Comment: It seems that the jni.h can not be found. Did you create the symbolic link to the include JDK directory? Please check whether there is the jni.h file.

Comment: Found out how to do it right! The problem was my symbolic link to the jdk. I had created it to the main folder, but it had to be created to the jdk/include-folder

Comment: mueldgog - thanks! I just saw your message - there's a first time for everything, this was my first .tar. Won't make the same mistake next time :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please use our new Java interface JSCIPOpt, which can be found [here](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/JSCIPOpt).