# The Java interface doesn't consider all constraints

Tags: scip

I've successfully generated the scip Java interface. During testing face, I've encountered this problem: the Java interface returns immediately a so called optimal solution (`problem is solved [optimal solution found]`), but some of the constraints are not being considered - the solution generated is a zero-solution (actually, not a solution).
I've tried running the same problem in scip binary in the terminal, and works fine. 
This is the problem that I'm testing:

```
param fichier:="/home/sebastien/workspace/DodenPlanning_teamDC/data.txt";
param nb_custom:= 11 ;
set Ind :=
{ read fichier as "<1s>" comment "#" use nb_custom} ;
param px[Ind] :=
read fichier as "<1s> 2n" comment "#" use nb_custom ; 
param py[Ind] :=
read fichier as "<1s> 3n" comment "#" use nb_custom;
defnumb dist(i,j)  := sqrt((px[i]-px[j])^2 + (py[i]-py[j])^2) ;
var x[Ind*Ind] binary ;
var r[Ind] integer <= card(Ind) - 1  ; # depot has rank 0, others have ranks 1 .. nb_points
minimize cost: sum <i,j> in Ind*Ind : dist(i,j) * x[i,j] ;
subto unique_predecessor : forall <j> in Ind do sum <i> in Ind : x[i,j]==1;
subto unique_successor : forall <j> in Ind do sum <k> in Ind : x[j,k]==1;
subto first_rank : r["0"] == 0 ; # because 0 is the starting point.
subto other_rank : # if there is edge i-> j then rank(j) = rank(i) + 1 
    forall <i,j> in Ind*Ind  with j != "0" do
        vif x[i,j] == 1 then r[j] == r[i] + 1 end ;
```

It's a modelisation of a VPR-problem. The solution returned by the interface is a solution where each vertex is only linked to himself (as this minimised the cost: equals 0), but this not a solution considering the other constraints.

We have verified that it is not a translation problem: a problem file was generated manually by simple and was solved by both ships binary in the terminal and by the Java interface.

The file is read by both: it generated the same number of variables, constraints etc.
Is the number of constraints limited in the Java interface? We have solved smaller problems which

Is the number of constraints limited in the Java interface? We have solved smaller problems which returned the same solution in both the scip binary and the Java interface.

Comment: Your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955663/interface-java-and-scip-not-generating-the-right-classes) and the answer suggest that you are now using [JSCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/JSCIPOpt), not the interfaces/jni in SCIP itself?

Comment: Yes: I used the JSCIPOpt to generate the scip.jar. It's imported into eclipse with a path to the native library scipoptsuite. It's when executing my problem though eclipse that the null-solution is returned. By null-solution I mean the zero solution.

Comment: I solved some *.zpl instances with JSCIPOpt and it worked fine. Could you check the first lines of the SCIP output and see whether SCIP is able to read your ZIMPL file?

Comment: It reads the right number of variables, constraints etc - exactly the same number as the SCIP binary, so to me it seems like the file is read correctly.

Comment: Could you add `scip.writeOrigProblem("orig.cip");` and check how orig.cip looks like? You can also write the original problem with SCIP and compare those two files.

Comment: When running the same problem file in scip and eclipse, I get two different solutions (yes, I checked again and again that I'm running the same file): This is what scip returns:

Comment: objective value:                     41.2970698203577
x$0$1                                               1  (obj:18.6815416922694)
x$1$2                                               1  (obj:2)
x$2$0                                               1  (obj:20.6155281280883)

Comment: and this is what I get from eclipse:

Comment: objective value:                                    0
x$0$0                                               1  (obj:0)
x$1$1                                               1  (obj:0)
x$2$2                                               1  (obj:0)

Comment: (there are more lines, but it's too long to put in a comment - I hope you see the picture. I only added the lines concerning the solution)

Comment: Advice for what to look for in the two .cip files? As you might have guessed, I have very little experience in this field.

Comment: After have looked closely at the two .cip-files: even though they have the same number of constraints, the file generated by Java contains 6 binary variables less than the one generated by scip. They have been "converted" from binary to integer variables.

Comment: from java:   Variables        : 42 (33 binary, 9 integer, 0 implicit integer, 0 continuous)

Comment: from scip:  Variables        : 42 (39 binary, 3 integer, 0 implicit integer, 0 continuous)

Comment: Can you add the content of `/home/sebastien/workspace/DodenPlanning_teamDC/data.txt`? What compiler do you use? What is your operating system? Did you compile the shared library that is necessary for JSCIPOpt on your own? Are you using the same SCIP version for the binary?

Comment: this is my gcc compiler and operating system:

Comment: Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)

Comment: this is the content of data.txt

Comment: #Nombre: 27

0 40 50

1 45 68

2 45 70

3 42 66

4 42 68

5 42 65

6 40 69

7 40 66

8 38 68

9 38 70

10 35 66

11 35 69

12 25 85

13 22 75

14 22 85

15 20 80

16 20 85

17 18 75

18 15 75

19 15 80

20 30 50

21 30 52

22 28 52

23 28 55

24 25 50

25 25 52

0 0 0

Comment: I'm using the same version of scip for java and the binary (the java library is linked to my scipoptsuite)

Comment: and finally, yes, I compiled the libraries on my own: I downloaded the scipoptsuite and JSCIPOpt and followed the installation instructions.

Comment: I hope the information given is adequate, let me know if you need to know more or if you need to contact me outside of this forum.

Comment: DId you compile SCIP without GMP? This library is necessary in order to use ZIMPL. If you compiled with GMP, could you try to run `zimpl *.zpl´' on the generated *.lp file?

Comment: Also, I ran your file and the generated model contains more than 600 integer variables. You reported that is contains around 40 binary variables...

Comment: In the end, we got around the problem in another way (we use the scip binary instead of the java-interface). Thank you for your time!